# Prestashop 1.6.1.14 - Set Conditions on hookDisplayPDFInvoice

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am trying to set conditions on the above stated hook - hookDisplayPDFInvoice. Based on the order ID, I would like to set a condition based on carrier name.

With great reference from below, I have managed to retrieve the order ID.

https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/397710-need-sample-code-on-how-to-use-displaypdfinvoice-hook/

I am trying to retrieve id_carrier based on the ID above. After-which, I would like to set a condition as follow (I was using this on hookActionValidateOrder, not working on hookDisplayPDFInvoice):

```
$carrier = new Carrier($params['order']->id_carrier);
if ($carrier->name=='XXX') {
    // My stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the hookDisplayPDFInvoice you can retrieve the carrier with this snippet:

```
$id_order = (int)$params['object']->id_order;
$order_obj = new Order($id_order);

// After retrieve the carrier
$carrier_obj = new Carrier((int)$order_obj->id_carrier);
```

You first have to retrieve the `id_order`, get the order object and then create the `Carrier` object